# How to make a formated EditText start from Right to Left using TextWatcher?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

**What I have:**

I have an EditText which accepts decimal input and I setted the default value in the XML to `0.00` *(if there is no input yet)*

If the user press `1`, then the value change to `1`. If he needs to enter decimal value then he must press the dot `.` on the keyboard.

**What I want:**

I want to auto format the EditText in a decimal format `0.00`, so if a user press `1` if becomes `0.01` instead of `1` (Like in the PAYPAL App). If he entered `100`, then the value in the EditText must be formatted as `1.00`.

I know this can be done by using `TextWatcher` but I don't know how to achieve this.

**End Result Comparison:**

*WHAT I HAVE*

1 = 1

11 = 11

222 = 222

*WHAT I NEED*

1 = 0.01

11 = 0.11

222 = 2.22

**UPDATE:**

My actual TextWatcher looks like below just to set the default value to `0.00` if the user deletes all inputs (to prevent error on calculated functions).

```
private class EditTextListener implements TextWatcher {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if (editText.getText().toString().equals("") || editText.length() < 1){
                editText.setText("0.00");
                editText.post(() -> editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()));
            } else {

                BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do post some code showing what you have done

Answer (score 0):

as you described you need to divide it by 100 with decimal points:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    
    if (editText.getText().toString().equals("") || editText.length() < 1) {
        editText.setText("0.00");
        editText.post(() -> editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()));
    } else {
        
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
        editText.setText(String.format("%.2f", (amount / 100.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: It converts as I wanted but cannot be setted back as value to the editText.
With this exemple I get a ``NumberFormatException for input String`` when the output is (0,05) if user pressed 5.
If I convert to the Locale.ENGLISH I get the output (0.05) but the app enter in infinite loop with huge Memory consuming then it shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code

```
edtQtdVolume.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    edtQtdVolume.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                    String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[R$,.]", "");

                    double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);

                    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");
                    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
                    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) nf;
                    formatter.applyPattern("#0.00");
                    String formatted = formatter.format((parsed/100));

                    edtQtdVolume.setText(formatted);
                    edtQtdVolume.setSelection(formatted.length());

                    edtQtdVolume.addTextChangedListener(this);

                    lista.get(position).setQtdVolumeInformadoColeta(Double.valueOf(formatted));
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


                }
            });
```